# How to show custom views like imageview or gif view in key board view

Tags: android, keyboard, android-textinputlayout, android-keypad

[in my keyboard view i need to show stickers and gif when click thos buttons in below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQnew.jpg)

Comment: Please give a full explanation

Comment: i need to show stickers in my custom key board. in above image it shows stickers in keyboard and when user clicks sticker its send in whats app group.thats what i need...now i created a normal keyboard using keyboard view.and how to change key board view to sticker view?

Comment: say explanation in your question.

Comment: i didnt get u..